# tilemill resolution

Tags: tiles, tilemill, mapnik

I have created a map on tilemill and can export the tiles to mbtiles. However I need to determine the resolution for each zoom level. On a previous project that used different technology (tilecache) I could call the following URL and it would return the resolutions.

/tilecache/tilecache.py?LAYERS=RSA&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

How do I get the resolutions for each zoom level in TileMill?